# Error 404 post name permalink wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, server, httpd.conf

I have just migrated my WordPress site from a Windows to a Linux server. Everything seems to work except the posts with the permalinks set to /%postname%/. I assumed this was `mod_overwrite` issue.

I have changed the httpconf file from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

And then reset the server just to make sure it took effect.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

I'm running Apache 2.2 on CentOS5 on a dedicated server.

To add: all the pages are working except the posts with these custom permalinks.

I have set permission to 666 for the .htaccess

Answer (score 5):

The same happened with me too. It turned out that `.htaccess` was not the issue for me. The issue was in server configuration file.

**For AWS EC2 server:**

**Step 1: Edit configuration file**

`sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Edit this file and change

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Note that here, `/var/www/html/wordpress/` is path to the root folder where WordPress project was hosted.

**Step 2: Restart server**

Please don't forget to restart your server after you do the changes to the `.conf` file.

`sudo service httpd restart`

**For Ubuntu server:**

**Step 1: Edit configuration file**

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Edit this file and change

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Note that here, `/var/www/html/wordpress/` is path to the root folder where WordPress project was hosted.

**Step 2: Restart server**

Please don't forget to restart your server after you do the changes to the `.conf` file.

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Amazon Linux config. It worked like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Keep AllowOverride none.

Remove the .htaccess file and any trace of that messy set of rewrite rules and just add this in virtualhost:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Neither mod_rewrite, neither .htaccess are needed.

By adding per-dir configurations you are basically complicating your life. Everything will be much harder to do, for what? to have dynamic changes by changing a file? .htaccess is meant for non-admin users who need to modify directory configurations.

Since you are the admin, configure everything possible in Virtualhost instead.

Giving rw permissions to everyone to files is definetly not the way to go either. httpd does not need write access to anything.